# socket.io, how do I get the event name from within the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

in `node.js` and `socket.io`, many events can be handled by one function:

```
socket.on( 'async.popular_qtns', rows.bind(socket) );
socket.on( 'async.recent_qtns', rows.bind(socket) );
socket.on( 'async.enum_chn', rows.bind(socket) );
socket.on( 'async.enum_tag', rows.bind(socket) );

function rows() {
  var socket = this;
  switch( socket.?? ) {
    case 'async.popular_qtns': // blah blah
        break;
    case 'async.recent_qtns': // blah blah
        break;
  }
}
```

how do I get the event name, eg, 'async.enum_tag' associated with the `socket.on()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the event name is reported to the callback function. You could try something like this:

```
var rowsBound = rows.bind(socket);

socket.on( 'async.popular_qtns', function() { rowsBound('asyn.popular_qtns'); } );
socket.on( 'async.recent_qtns', function() { rowsBound('asyn.recent_qtns'); } );
socket.on( 'async.enum_chn', function() { rowsBound('asyn.enum_chn'); } );
socket.on( 'async.enum_tag', function() { rowsBound('asyn.enum_tag'); } );
```

Or, probably better:

```
var rowsBound = rows.bind(socket),
    events = ['async.popular_qtns', 'async.recent_qtns', 'async.enum_chn', 'async.enum_tag'];

for (var i in events)
    (function(e) { socket.on(e, function() { rowsBound(e); }); })(events[i]);
```

Comment: You should consider passing the additional argument as an argument to bind: `socket.on(e, rows.bind(socket, e));` Then you can also get rid of the other function and have the loop be `for (...) socket.on(events[i], rows.bind(socket, events[i]));`

Comment: @Matt Bradley - that's what I'm finding - no reference to the name.  which seems counter-intuitive to me, esp considering how much everything else in node seems to be linked together exhaustively.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may use [express.io](https://npmjs.org/package/express.io) with [express.io-middleware](https://npmjs.org/package/express.io-middleware), which adds req.io.event, which store event name and req.io.namespaces which store first part of event name, splitted by ':'.